# Approval in Azure Devops YAML pipeline without virtual machine

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

Let's say I have a YAML pipeline, releasing to dev and prod, and I want to set an approval before releasing to production.
Currently, this can be done via Environments approvals ([MS Docs - Define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass)).

However, this seems to work only for virtual machines.

**How can I set an approval when releasing to Azure PaaS components, e.g. Azure function or Azure App Service?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, go to service connection that is used to connect to cloud env, and set the approval there.

Project settings -> service connections -> select your connection (prod) -> click the three dots -> approvals and checks.

Answer (score 0):

In your pipeline you need to define a [deployment job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops), specifying an [Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops) which is configured to require an [Approval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass).